# Google Charts: Combining ChartRangeFilter with Data Series Selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, google-visualization

I have a large set of 8 series of data over time, and currently I have two working graphs, one that has a range selector (allowing you to slide a bar to select which dates to show), and the other has the ability to click on the chart legend to choose which of the series to show and which of the series to hide.

I haven't been able to combine them together, though, into one unified dashboard that does both together. This particular code allows you to filter the date, but hiding/showing a series doesn't work. I've tried various combinations in place of the last line (chart.draw(view);) such as redrawing the dashboard and rebinding the dashboard, but still can't get it working. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Here's the relevant code (edit to include sample json_obj):

```
    var json_obj = {
            "cols": [{ "label": "Date", "type": "date" },
            { "label": "F1", "type": "number" },
            { "label": "F2", "type": "number" },
            { "label": "F3", "type": "number" },
            { "label": "F4", "type": "number" }],
            "rows": [{
                    "c": [{ "v": Date(6,1,14) },
                        { "v": .25 },
                        { "v": .55 },
                        { "v": .12 },
                        { "v": .067 }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "c": [{ "v": Date(6,2,14) },
                        { "v": .27 },
                        { "v": .52 },
                        { "v": .18 },
                        { "v": .055 }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "c": [{ "v": Date(6,3,14) },
                        { "v": .30 },
                        { "v": .60 },
                        { "v": .17 },
                        { "v": .043 }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "c": [{ "v": Date(6,4,14) },
                        { "v": .33 },
                        { "v": .57 },
                        { "v": .14 },
                        { "v": .05 }
                    ]
                }]
        };
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(json_obj);

var formatter = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({
    pattern: '#.###%'
});

for (i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
    formatter.format(data, i);
}

var dashboard = new google.visualization.Dashboard(
    document.getElementById('dashboard'));

var columns = [];
var series = {};
for (var i = 0; i < data.getNumberOfColumns() ; i++) {
    columns.push(i);
    if (i > 0) {
        series[i - 1] = {};
    }
}

var control = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
    controlType: 'ChartRangeFilter',
    containerId: 'control',
    options: {
        // Filter by the date axis.
        filterColumnIndex: 0,
        ui: {
            chartType: 'LineChart',
            chartOptions: {
                hAxis: {
                    baselineColor: 'none',
                    format: 'MM/dd/yy'
                }
            },
            // 1 day in milliseconds = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1 * 1000 = 86400000
            minRangeSize: 86400000
        }
    }
});

var chart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
    chartType: 'LineChart',
    containerId: 'chart',
    options: {
        title: 'Feature Users Over Time',
        vAxis: {
            title: "Percent of Users",
            format: '#.###%',
            viewWindow: { min: 0 }
        },
            lineWidth: 2,
            curveType: 'function',
            series: series
    }
});

dashboard.bind(control, chart);
dashboard.draw(data);

google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'select', function () {
    var sel = chart.getSelection();
    // if selection length is 0, we deselected an element
    if (sel.length > 0) {
        // if row is undefined, we clicked on the legend
        if (sel[0].row === null) {
            var col = sel[0].column;
            if (columns[col] == col) {
                // hide the data series
                columns[col] = {
                    label: data.getColumnLabel(col),
                    type: data.getColumnType(col),
                    calc: function () {
                        return null;
                    }
                };

                // grey out the legend entry
                series[col - 1].color = '#CCCCCC';
            }
            else {
                // show the data series
                columns[col] = col;
                series[col - 1].color = null;
            }
            var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
            view.setColumns(columns);
            chart.draw(view);
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If row can be 'undefined' then you need to check:

```
if (!sel[0].row)
```

..or

```
if (sel[0].row == 0)
```

..instead of

```
if (sel[0].row === null)
```

..because the result are different in each case.

See http://jsfiddle.net/3wcd3w7x/2/

Edit: for fix jsfiddle example.

Answer (score 0):

You almost have it; you need to change the chart's `series` option and set the chart's `view` parameter instead of creating a DataView.  Replace these lines:

```
var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
view.setColumns(columns);
chart.draw(view);
```

with these:

```
chart.setOption('series', series);
chart.setView({columns: columns});
chart.draw();
```

Comment: This didn't seem to fix the issue :/ I still get an 'Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function'

Comment: Can you update your question with a sample of `json_obj` so I can test this?

Comment: Updated with a sample json_obj. Thanks.